# Apache: SSI is Corrupting My File

Tags: apache, server-side-includes

I have a java script file being served by Apache, in production this works fine, and emits in part, something like this:

```
window.dhtmlHistory.create({toJSON: function(o) {
   return common.toJSON(o);
} , fromJSON: function(s) {
    return eval('(' + s + ')');
}});
```

But in my local development environment, the exact same file becomes this:

```
w+cont.dhtmlHistory.c.show({toJSON: fail]mdo(o) {
    -wrappecommon.toJSON(o);
} , fromJSON: fail]mdo(s) {
    -wrappeeval('(' + s + ')');
}});
```

The main difference I am currently aware of is that from the response headers, the version on the production server is

```
Server:Apache/2.4.6 (Amazon) PHP/5.4.17
```

And my local version is

```
Server:Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) DAV/2
```

One more detail that may be relevant here is that this is plain text in the file that is not being subjected to the server side include, it is in the file which includes others, but otherwise it should not be modified by Apache.  What could be going on here and how can I go about diagnosing it and fixing it?

Comment: Upgrade your local server to the production version. If anything it should be ahead, not dozens of versions behind.

Comment: I tried that, but this is the version that comes with yum.  I tried building 2.4 from source, but that opened up a larger can of worms based on non backward compatibility.  You haven't answered why or how mod_include could munge source this badly.

Comment: By the way @EJP, everyone else here is having a fine time with 2.2.14 and 2.2.15, this is not a version issue.

Comment: Maybe show the config files and .htaccess files, the clues to the problem could be there. As it stands, there isn't enough info.